# Compare two date columns in pandas and assign labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with customer transactions as shown below how can I achieve the below outcome (compare transaction end date and transaction start date columns)

The labels to be created are

1. Start date appeared earlier in the end date column.
2. Start date did not appear earlier in the end date column.

**Input**

```
Transaction ID   Transaction Start Date  Transaction End Date 
      1             27-Oct-2014              11-Nov-2014
      2             29-Oct-2014              30-Nov-2014        
      3             11-Nov-2014              20-Nov-2014        
      4             15-Nov-2014              28-Nov-2014      
      5             20-Nov-2014              05-Dec-2014
      6             28-Nov-2014              15-Dec-2014
      7             29-Nov-2014              20-Dec-2014
```

**Desired output**

```
Transaction ID   Transaction Start Date  Transaction End Date  Label
      1             27-Oct-2014              11-Nov-2014       
      2             29-Oct-2014              30-Nov-2014       start date did not appear earlier in the end date column
      3             11-Nov-2014              20-Nov-2014       start date appeared earlier in end date column 
      4             15-Nov-2014              28-Nov-2014       start date did not appear earlier in the end date column
      5             20-Nov-2014              05-Dec-2014       start date appeared earlier in end date column 
      6             28-Nov-2014              15-Dec-2014       start date appeared earlier in the end date column
      7             29-Nov-2014              20-Dec-2014       start date did not appear earlier in the end date column
```

Comment: Is possible explain why `Transaction ID=4` is `start date did not appear earlier in the end date column` ? What dates are compared?

Comment: Also why first 2 missing?

Comment: @jezrael,Thanks I have updated the question.I am trying to compare the Transaction End date with all the dates in the Transaction start date column and check if the Transaction Start date appeared earlier in the Transaction End Date column.

Comment: What dates are compared for `Transaction ID=4` ?

Comment: @jezrael,the same transaction end date and transaction start date is compared for Transaction ID=4 Transaction start date 15 Nov-2014 has no matches in the Transaction End Date column for Transaction IDs =1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert values to datetimes
df['Transaction End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction End Date'])
df['Transaction Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction Start Date'])

#check if previous values exist in list comprehenion
mask = [df['Transaction End Date'].iloc[:i].eq(x).any() 
        for i, x in enumerate(df['Transaction Start Date'])]

#set labels
df['Label'] = np.where(mask, 
                        'start date appeared earlier in end date column', 
                        'start date did not appear earlier in the end date column')

#set first value to empty string
df.loc[0, 'Label'] = ''
print (df)
   Transaction ID Transaction Start Date Transaction End Date  \
0               1             2014-10-27           2014-11-11   
1               2             2014-10-29           2014-11-30   
2               3             2014-11-11           2014-11-20   
3               4             2014-11-15           2014-11-28   
4               5             2014-11-20           2014-12-05   
5               6             2014-11-28           2014-12-15   
6               7             2014-11-29           2014-12-20   

                                               Label  
0                                                     
1  start date did not appear earlier in the end d...  
2     start date appeared earlier in end date column  
3  start date did not appear earlier in the end d...  
4     start date appeared earlier in end date column  
5     start date appeared earlier in end date column  
6  start date did not appear earlier in the end d...
```